# adding a custom method to Meta class in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, metadata

I have an AbstractBase model class that gets inherited by several models in their respective apps. I want the user to be able to set a name that will be used in the verbose_name field in the Meta class. If a user provides a name in one of the fields in the AbstractBase model, then that field will be used as the verbose name

this is what I have tried so far

```
class AbstractBase(models.Model):
   ......
   custom_name = models.CharField(blank=True)

   class Meta(object):
      abstract = True

      def update_verbose_name(self, custom_name):
          if self.project_setting is not None:
              return verbose_name == self.custom_name
```

when I run this it gives me `TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): update_verbose_name`

is there another way that I solve this?

Comment: That does not seem like a great idea to begin with. A model has many instances, how do you choose which one is supposed to be the one that holds the verbose name?

Comment: ill be using the meta inheritance in models that I want the user to be able to update verbose name

` class Student(AbstractBase):
    # ...
    class Meta(AbstractBase.Meta):
        odering = name

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the indentation like this:

```
class AbstractBase(models.Model):
   ......
   custom_name = models.CharField(blank=True)

   def update_verbose_name(self, custom_name):
       if self.project_setting is not None:
           return verbose_name == self.custom_name

   class Meta(object):
      abstract = True
```

Comment: the problem with this method is I won't be able to access those variable outside the class

Comment: if you do an `AbstractBase` it implies that you want classes to inherit from this class... so all descendants will have access to `self.custom_name`, and from the outside you will be able to access to `custom_name` property. I dont see your problem then...